# Is it possible to embed a OneNote search in a OneNote page?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

In OneNote it is easy to add a link to a OneNote page or section. It is also easy to search a OneNote for a word or phrase. Can I embed a link to a OneNote search into a OneNote page?